# I don't understand how to prove the equation for this force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I got this excercise that I need to solve. I have tried to draw on forces, but I think I have done something wrong. I have also tried to equate the sides of the triangle. Still I don't understand how the force P is supposed to be calculated from the given equation. Could someone give me a few hints please.

[image: The drawing of the excercise]

Excercise text:
A rod AB with mass m is articulated at point A and supported by a block at point D. The block can
move frictionlessly in the horizontal plane. A horizontal force P acts on the block, see the figure. It is no friction in D. The resultant of the dead weight mg to the rod attacks in the center of gravity of the rod. Show that P equates this:

[image: The formula for P]

The hint I got for the excercise:
Since there is no friction, the force at point D must be oriented perpendicular to the rod AB.
The mass of the block has no significance when there is no friction between the block and the substrate.

This is what I have done until now:

[image: The forces]

[image]

Comment: Are they asking for the force $P$ required for the rod and block to be in static equilibrium? It is not clear to me what they are asking.

Comment: @BobD It must be that: equilibrium. Otherwise some acceleration would have been specified. It's a very boring and tedious statics problem.

Comment: @Gert agree it must be

Comment: @BobD t's a static equlibrium problem. The acceleration isn't given in the excercise.

Comment: It's probably easiest to set the torque about the pivot to be 0 to compute F.  Then from F you can compute P.  It is just a matter of keeping components straight.

Comment: @BillWatts yes I am going to try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with energies if you like, the claim that the system is in a static equilibrium is a claim that the system does not change energy by moving one way or another.

Consider a small angle change $\delta\theta$ on the bar, say $\theta=0$ the bar is on the ground, then the change causes an energy loss  $mg~\cos\theta~\delta\theta~L/2.$ Meanwhile the $x$-coordinate of the block can be understood, if we accept as constraint that it keeps touching the bar, as being given by $x=h/\tan\theta$ and we know that the derivative of cotangent is cosecant squared, so the other work at play looks like $P~h~\delta\theta/\sin^2\theta$,  and so we can immediately “see” the answer as $\sin^2\theta\cos\theta.$

Of course that is not how your teacher wants you to do this, so maybe that is not very much help. However, you have that $|P|=|F_x|$ to keep the block stationary, then $|F_z|=|F_x|\tan\theta$ from the hint that your teacher has given you, and now you just need to do the energy argument again, but this time it takes the form of an argument about the torque on the bar. The claim is that the forces on the bar should be in torque balance. So you have this force $\sqrt{F_x^2+F_z^2}\propto1/\sin \theta$ at radius $\sqrt{x^2+h^2}=h/\sin\theta$ trying to balance against this force of gravity which is acting at angle $\theta$ to the bar and must be projected relative to it, giving a $\cos\theta$ term. So we again get this $\sin^2\theta\cos\theta$ term that way, too, if I am doing my hand waving properly.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I thought about the same thing. You have given me some idea how to solve this question. Thank you so much for your help!